GRUB not showing support for all possible video modes
GRUB not showing support for all possible video modes. (Using Debian 12)  GRUB only shows support for 1280x1024 maximum, but once GNOME is up, 1920x1080@60 shown per the XWAYLAND0 device.
Why this difference?
How can GRUB show parity to what the GNOME UI supports?

Which computer model and does it use BIOS or UEFI? What do you have in /etc/default/grub?

It is an older Dell 540 Stdio PC.  Runs Linux well, even Windows 10 OK.  It is BIOS based.  GRUB_DEFAULT="0" GRUB_TIMEOUT="5" GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian" GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet video=VGA-1:1920x1080@60" GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="" GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="false" GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD="keep" export GRUB_MENU_PICTURE="/boot/grub/grub.png" export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-gray/black" export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="white/red"

Please Edit the information into your post. Inside a comment it's not very readable. (Add to your comment @harrymc for me to be notified.)
